# Animation method not working inside if statement

Tags: java, animation

I'm trying to create an animation once the enemy dies. Using an if statement like so

**Enemy.class (ONLY A SECTION)**

```
public void tick() {
        y += speed;

        if (y > Game.HEIGHT * Game.SCALE) {
            speed = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
            x = r.nextInt(540);
            y = -10;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < game.ea.size(); i++) {
            EntityA tempEnt = game.ea.get(i);

            if (Physics.Collision(this, tempEnt)) {


                explo.runAnimation(); // THIS SHOULD RUN WHEN ENEMY DIES
                c.removeEntity(tempEnt);
                c.removeEntity(this);
                game.setEnemyKilled(game.getEnemyKilled() + 1);         
            }

        }

        anim.runAnimation();

    }
```

this unfortunately doesn't work, although if I put explo.runAnimation(); next to anim.runAnimation(); it does work, although I don't need it there...

This is the whole Enemy.class

**Enemy.class**

```
package com.game.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;

import com.game.main.classes.EntityA;
import com.game.main.classes.EntityB;
import com.game.main.libs.Animation;

public class Enemy extends GameObject implements EntityB {

    private Textures tex;
    Random r = new Random();
    private Game game;
    private Controller c;

    private int speed = r.nextInt(3) + 1;

    Animation anim;
    Animation explo;

    public Enemy(double x, double y, Textures tex, Controller c, Game game) {
        super(x, y);
        this.tex = tex;
        this.c = c;
        this.game = game;

        anim = new Animation(5, tex.enemy[0], tex.enemy[1], tex.enemy[2]);
        explo = new Animation(5, tex.explosion[0], tex.explosion[1], tex.explosion[2], tex.explosion[3]);
    }

    public void tick() {
        y += speed;

        if (y > Game.HEIGHT * Game.SCALE) {
            speed = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
            x = r.nextInt(540);
            y = -10;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < game.ea.size(); i++) {
            EntityA tempEnt = game.ea.get(i);

            if (Physics.Collision(this, tempEnt)) {


                explo.runAnimation();
                c.removeEntity(tempEnt);
                c.removeEntity(this);
                game.setEnemyKilled(game.getEnemyKilled() + 1);         
            }

        }

        anim.runAnimation();

    }


    public void render(Graphics g) {
        anim.drawAnimation(g, x, y, 0);
        explo.drawAnimation(g, x, y, 0);
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle((int) x, (int) y, 32, 32);
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

}
```

This is the Physics class

**Physics.class**

```
package com.game.main;

import com.game.main.classes.EntityA;
import com.game.main.classes.EntityB;

public class Physics {

    public static boolean Collision(EntityA enta, EntityB entb){

        if(enta.getBounds().intersects(entb.getBounds())){
                return true;
    }

        return false;
    }

public static boolean Collision(EntityB entb, EntityA enta){


            if(entb.getBounds().intersects(enta.getBounds())){
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

This is the controller class, the class that handles the enemies and removes one if need be, used by :

```
 c.removeEntity(tempEnt);
                c.removeEntity(this);
```

**Controller.class**

```
package com.game.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

import com.game.main.classes.EntityA;
import com.game.main.classes.EntityB;
import com.game.main.libs.Animation;

public class Controller {

    private LinkedList<EntityA> ea = new LinkedList<EntityA>();
    private LinkedList<EntityB> eb = new LinkedList<EntityB>();

    EntityA enta;
    EntityB entb;

    private Textures tex;
    Random r = new Random();
    private Game game;

    public Controller(Textures tex, Game game){
        this.tex = tex;
        this.game = game;


    }

    public void createEnemy(int enemyCount){
        for(int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++){
            addEntity(new Enemy(r.nextInt(640), -10, tex, this, game)); //Knows enemy is a B class as it extends it

        }
    }

    public void tick(){
        //A Class
        for(int i = 0; i < eb.size(); i++){
            entb = eb.get(i);

            entb.tick();
        }

        //B Class
                for(int i = 0; i < ea.size(); i++){
                    enta = ea.get(i);

                    enta.tick();
                }



    }

    public void render(Graphics g){

        //A class
        for(int i = 0; i < ea.size(); i++){
            enta = ea.get(i);

            enta.render(g);
        }

        //B class
                for(int i = 0; i < eb.size(); i++){
                    entb = eb.get(i);

                    entb.render(g);
                }

    }

    public void addEntity(EntityA block){
        ea.add(block);
    }

    public void removeEntity(EntityA block){
        ea.remove(block);


    }

    public void addEntity(EntityB block){
        eb.add(block);
    }

    public void removeEntity(EntityB block){
        eb.remove(block);
    }

    public LinkedList<EntityA> getEntityA(){
        return ea;
    }
    public LinkedList<EntityB> getEntityB(){
        return eb;
    }

    }
```

This is the Animation class, `explo` and `anim` use.

**Animation.class**

```
package com.game.main.libs;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Animation {

    private int speed;
    private int frames;
    private int index = 0;
    private int count = 0;

    private BufferedImage img1;
    private BufferedImage img2;
    private BufferedImage img3;
    private BufferedImage img4;
    private BufferedImage img5;
    private BufferedImage img6;
    private BufferedImage img7;
    private BufferedImage img8;
    private BufferedImage img9;
    private BufferedImage img10;
    private BufferedImage img11;
    private BufferedImage img12;
    private BufferedImage img13;
    private BufferedImage img14;

    private BufferedImage currentImg;
    //14 frame animation
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5, BufferedImage img6, BufferedImage img7, BufferedImage img8, BufferedImage img9, BufferedImage img10, BufferedImage img11, BufferedImage img12, BufferedImage img13, BufferedImage img14){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        this.img6 = img6;
        this.img7 = img7;
        this.img8 = img8;
        this.img9 = img9;
        this.img10 = img10;
        this.img11 = img11;
        this.img12 = img12;
        this.img13 = img13;
        this.img14 = img14;
        frames = 14;
    }
    //13 frame animation
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5, BufferedImage img6, BufferedImage img7, BufferedImage img8, BufferedImage img9, BufferedImage img10, BufferedImage img11, BufferedImage img12, BufferedImage img13){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        this.img6 = img6;
        this.img7 = img7;
        this.img8 = img8;
        this.img9 = img9;
        this.img10 = img10;
        this.img11 = img11;
        this.img12 = img12;
        this.img13 = img13;
        frames = 13;
        }
    //12 frame animation
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5, BufferedImage img6, BufferedImage img7, BufferedImage img8, BufferedImage img9, BufferedImage img10, BufferedImage img11, BufferedImage img12){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        this.img6 = img6;
        this.img7 = img7;
        this.img8 = img8;
        this.img9 = img9;
        this.img10 = img10;
        this.img11 = img11;
        this.img12 = img12;
        frames = 12;
    }
    //11 frame animation
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5, BufferedImage img6, BufferedImage img7, BufferedImage img8, BufferedImage img9, BufferedImage img10, BufferedImage img11){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        this.img6 = img6;
        this.img7 = img7;
        this.img8 = img8;
        this.img9 = img9;
        this.img10 = img10;
        this.img11 = img11;
        frames = 11;
    }
    //10 frame animation
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5, BufferedImage img6, BufferedImage img7, BufferedImage img8, BufferedImage img9, BufferedImage img10){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        this.img6 = img6;
        this.img7 = img7;
        this.img8 = img8;
        this.img9 = img9;
        this.img10 = img10;
        frames = 10;
    }
    // 9 frame
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5, BufferedImage img6, BufferedImage img7, BufferedImage img8, BufferedImage img9){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        this.img6 = img6;
        this.img7 = img7;
        this.img8 = img8;
        this.img9 = img9;
        frames = 9;
    }
    //8 frame
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5, BufferedImage img6, BufferedImage img7, BufferedImage img8){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        this.img6 = img6;
        this.img7 = img7;
        this.img8 = img8;
        frames = 8;
    }
    //7 frame
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5, BufferedImage img6, BufferedImage img7){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        this.img6 = img6;
        this.img7 = img7;
        frames = 7;
    }
    //6 frame
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5, BufferedImage img6){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        this.img6 = img6;
        frames = 6;
    }
    //5 frame
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4, BufferedImage img5){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        this.img5 = img5;
        frames = 5;
    }
    //4 frame
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3, BufferedImage img4){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        this.img4 = img4;
        frames = 4;
    }
    //3 frame
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2, BufferedImage img3){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        this.img3 = img3;
        frames = 3;
    }
    //2 frame
    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.img1 = img1;
        this.img2 = img2;
        frames = 2;
    }

    public void runAnimation(){
        index++;
        if(index > speed){
            index = 0;
            nextFrame();
        }   
    }

    public void nextFrame(){

        //switch statement
        switch(frames){
        case 2:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 3:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 4:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 5:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 6:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;
            if(count == 5)
                currentImg = img6;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 7:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;
            if(count == 5)
                currentImg = img6;
            if(count == 6)
                currentImg = img7;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 8:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;
            if(count == 5)
                currentImg = img6;
            if(count == 6)
                currentImg = img7;
            if(count == 7)
                currentImg = img8;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 9:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;
            if(count == 5)
                currentImg = img6;
            if(count == 6)
                currentImg = img7;
            if(count == 7)
                currentImg = img8;
            if(count == 8)
                currentImg = img9;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;  
        case 10:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;
            if(count == 5)
                currentImg = img6;
            if(count == 6)
                currentImg = img7;
            if(count == 7)
                currentImg = img8;
            if(count == 8)
                currentImg = img9;
            if(count == 9)
                currentImg = img10;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 11:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;
            if(count == 5)
                currentImg = img6;
            if(count == 6)
                currentImg = img7;
            if(count == 7)
                currentImg = img8;
            if(count == 8)
                currentImg = img9;
            if(count == 9)
                currentImg = img10;
            if(count == 10)
                currentImg = img11;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 12:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;
            if(count == 5)
                currentImg = img6;
            if(count == 6)
                currentImg = img7;
            if(count == 7)
                currentImg = img8;
            if(count == 8)
                currentImg = img9;
            if(count == 9)
                currentImg = img10;
            if(count == 10)
                currentImg = img11;
            if(count == 11)
                currentImg = img12;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 13:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;
            if(count == 5)
                currentImg = img6;
            if(count == 6)
                currentImg = img7;
            if(count == 7)
                currentImg = img8;
            if(count == 8)
                currentImg = img9;
            if(count == 9)
                currentImg = img10;
            if(count == 10)
                currentImg = img11;
            if(count == 11)
                currentImg = img12;
            if(count == 12)
                currentImg = img13;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        case 14:
            if(count == 0)
                currentImg = img1;
            if(count == 1)
                currentImg = img2;
            if(count == 2)
                currentImg = img3;
            if(count == 3)
                currentImg = img4;
            if(count == 4)
                currentImg = img5;
            if(count == 5)
                currentImg = img6;
            if(count == 6)
                currentImg = img7;
            if(count == 7)
                currentImg = img8;
            if(count == 8)
                currentImg = img9;
            if(count == 9)
                currentImg = img10;
            if(count == 10)
                currentImg = img11;
            if(count == 11)
                currentImg = img12;
            if(count == 12)
                currentImg = img13;
            if(count == 13)
                currentImg = img14;

            count++;

            if(count > frames)
                count = 0;

            break;
        }
    }

    public void drawAnimation(Graphics g, double x, double y, int offset){
        g.drawImage(currentImg, (int)x - offset, (int)y, null);
    }

    public void setCount(int count){
        this.count = count;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }
    public void setSpeed(int speed){
        this.speed = speed;
    }

}
```

The main game class where everything is put together

**Game.class**

Comment: I'm assuming that removing the entity means that it can no longer be painted?  Maybe you should remove the entity AFTER the death animation has completed?

Comment: Shouldn't putting explo.runAnimation(); before it do it? Or is there some sort of method I can use?

Comment: But if you the entity, how does the animation get painted?

Comment: Ohh right, sorry. I understand, the render(Graphics g) method? How would i make sure that the entity dies after the death animation is completed?

Comment: How does the `Animation` class know when it's done?  Can it trigger and event?  Maybe have a pool of entities that need to be removed after their associated `Animation` is complete?

Comment: Ah, doesn't seem like it can trigger an event, that seems like the right idea! I'll focus on it tommorow as it is quite late here

Comment: @MadProgrammer If you want to, you can post it as an answer and I'd be happy to tick it, you got me into the right track, although I haven't finished it yet. I'll ask for more help if need be, thanks again :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The animation does know when it is finished, but how would I be able to get it to trigger a removal of an entity?

Comment: Use some kind of call back to the entity manager...